# Is there a way to return multiple elements of a list without having to type them out?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to model the amplification/multiplication of DNA fragments (STRs) in PCR. I am considering allele, stutter, and stutter of stutter (stutter2) for each locus and assuming I have two copies of each, e.g., Allele 1 and 2 from mom and dad, same for stutter and stutter2. I also incorporate PCR efficiency (per locus) that depends on the number of amplicons I produce at every PCR cycle. Theoretically, the number of amplicons doubles at every cycle such that at the end of the cycle, n, I’ll have 2^n copies of DNA but in my model, I use a binomial function to estimate the number of amplicons, which is more consistent with experimental data. For PCR efficiency, it decreases with an increase in PCR products. I have two problems; the first is that I want to return allele 1 & 2, stutter (of allele 1 & 2), stutter2 (of allele 1 & 2), and PCR efficiency for 21 loci, and what I have done in my function is list all four variables for each of the 2 loci, namely D3S1358 and vWA. I have 19 more loci to add. Is there a way to add them without having to write them out one by one in my return statement? Here is the complete list of loci: D3S1358, vWA, D16S539, CSF1PO, TPOX, D8S1179, D21S11, D18S51, D2S441, D19S433, TH01, FGA, D22S1045, D5S818, D13S317, D7S820, SE33, D10S1248, D1S1656, D12S391, D2S1338
My second question is whether there is a more efficient way to store the data since I currently have a data frame. I want to keep the data in such a way that I am able to use the final values (at the end of total cycle number) of each variable to do some calculations, e.g., use Allele 1 of locus D3S1358 to do some basic math on it. Here is my function below:

```r
# Amplification of DNA fragments/alleles using PCR
pcr <- function(initial_efficiency, num_cycles) {
  
prob_stutter <- 0.006
  amplicon_count_allele1 <- c()
  amplicon_count_allele2 <- c()
  stutter_count_allele1 <- c()
  stutter_count_allele2 <- c()
  stutter2_count_allele1 <- c()
  stutter2_count_allele2 <- c()
  efficiency_allele <- c()
  
  efficiency_allele[1] <- initial_efficiency # efficiency at cycle 1 
  amplicon_count_allele1[1] <- 1 # Starting with 1 amplicon for allele 1
  amplicon_count_allele2[1] <- 1 # Starting with 1 amplicon for allele 2
  stutter_count_allele1[1] <- 0 # Starting with 0 stutter products for allele 1
  stutter_count_allele2[1] <- 0 # Starting with 0 stutter products for allele 2
  stutter2_count_allele1[1] <- 0 # Starting with 0 stutter of stutter for allele 1
  stutter2_count_allele2[1] <- 0 # Starting with 0 stutter of stutter for allele 2
  
  for (i in 2:num_cycles) {
    # DNA amplicon allele 1
    amplicon_count_allele1[i] <- amplicon_count_allele1[i-1] + 
      sum(rbinom(amplicon_count_allele1[i-1], 1, efficiency_allele)) 
    # DNA amplicon allele 2
    amplicon_count_allele2[i] <- amplicon_count_allele2[i-1] + 
      sum(rbinom(amplicon_count_allele2[i-1], 1, efficiency_allele))
    # Stutter from allele 1
    stutter_count_allele1[i] <- stutter_count_allele1[i-1] + 
      sum(rbinom(amplicon_count_allele1[i-1], 1, prob_stutter)) + 
      sum(rbinom(stutter_count_allele1[i-1], 1, prob_stutter))
    # Stutter from allele 2
    stutter_count_allele2[i] <- stutter_count_allele2[i-1] + 
      sum(rbinom(amplicon_count_allele2[i-1], 1, prob_stutter)) + 
      sum(rbinom(stutter_count_allele2[i-1], 1, prob_stutter))
    # Stutter 2 allele 1
    stutter2_count_allele1[i] <- stutter2_count_allele1[i-1] + 
      sum(rbinom(stutter_count_allele1[i-1], 1, prob_stutter)) +
      sum(rbinom(stutter2_count_allele1[i-1],1,prob_stutter))
    # Stutter 2 allele 2
    stutter2_count_allele2[i] <- stutter2_count_allele2[i-1] + 
      sum(rbinom(stutter_count_allele2[i-1], 1, prob_stutter)) +
      sum(rbinom(stutter2_count_allele2[i-1],1, prob_stutter))
    # PCR efficiency
    efficiency_allele[i] <- efficiency_allele[i-1] * exp(-1.12*10^(-12)*
                                                     (amplicon_count_allele1[i]+
                                                      amplicon_count_allele2[i]+
                                                      stutter_count_allele1[i]+
                                                      stutter_count_allele2[i]+
                                                      stutter2_count_allele1[i]+
                                                      stutter2_count_allele2[i]))
    
  }
  # Return Allele, Stutter, Stutter2 and PCR efficiency for each locus 
  return(data.frame("D3S1358 Allele 1" = amplicon_count_allele1,
                    "D3S1358 Allele 2" = amplicon_count_allele2,
              "D3S1358 Stutter Allele 1"=stutter_count_allele1,
              "D3S1358 Stutter Allele 2"=stutter_count_allele2,
              "D3S1358 Stutter2 Allele 1" = stutter2_count_allele1,
              "D3S1358 Stutter2 Allele 2" = stutter2_count_allele2,
              "PCR Efficiency D3S1358" = efficiency_allele,
              "vWA Allele 1" = amplicon_count_allele1,
              "vWA Allele 2" = amplicon_count_allele2,
              "vWA Stutter Allele 1"=stutter_count_allele1,
              "vWA Stutter Allele 2"=stutter_count_allele2,
              "vWA Stutter2 Allele 1" = stutter2_count_allele1,
              "vWA Stutter2 Allele 2" = stutter2_count_allele2,
              "PCR Efficiency vWA" = efficiency_allele))
}
```

Comment: You are still at the very beginning of R. Anyway if you are doing the same thing to all the vectors why not write A function and call it on the vectors?

Comment: I am very new to coding. I'm just learning R along the way. I have been using vba excel. At any case, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To get better, faster help, try to parse this down to a *minimal* and *reproducible* example. We dont need your full, or even representative, data if this could be represented with simpler toy data

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. There's a lot of code here, but we can't run any of it without any of the necessary data. There's also a lot of vocab from whatever field you're in that I wouldn't assume most of us know (I sure don't) but it doesn't seem necessary to the actual question anyway. If the question is just about subsetting and storing lists, you can just make dummy data that recreates that situation